# What PL/pgSQL exception is the equivalent for Oracle's VALUE_ERROR in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I am writing an function with exception equivalent to catch what is a `VALUE_ERROR` in Oracle in PostgreSQL.  Is there any replacement in PostgreSQL?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST (a TEXT, b TEXT)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $SUCCESS$
DECLARE SUCCESS INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SUCCESS = 0;
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TABLE_TEST
        SET *****
        WHERE ***;
        SUCCESS = 1;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN VALUE_ERROR /* throwing error as there is no value-error in postgres */
        SUCCESS = 0;

        UPDATE TABLE_TEST
        SET *****
        WHERE ***;
        SUCCESS = 2;

       WHEN OTHERS THEN
        SUCCESS = 3;

        UPDATE TABLE_TEST
        SET *****
        WHERE ***;
        SUCCESS = 4;
    END;

   RETURN SUCCESS;
END;
$SUCCESS$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In place of the `value_error` exception, it should be the equivalent in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why don't you just perform the operation in postgres and see what type of exception is raised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `data_exception`, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

This is actually a class of exceptions that encompasses all that can go wrong with data, but I'd say it is the best replacement.

Comment: @Syedasamreenanjum Please accept answer if it solved your problem.